# Scrollview issue - scroll_y not updating after rows added to scrollview

Tags: python, kivy

I've noticed that the scroll_y value is being reset to 0.0 when new rows are added to an existing scrollview. This is a problem because I need to know the new scroll_y value as rows are added to the existing scrollview.

After adding new rows to the scrollview, I can obtain the new scroll_y value after manually scrolling the mouse wheel down (via on scroll stop). However, I need to know the new scroll_y value right after the code adds new rows to the view and moves the scrollbar upwards like in the below example.

How do I obtain the new scroll_y value after new rows are added to the scrollview and the bar is moved using code?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Line, InstructionGroup, Canvas, CanvasBase, Color, Rectangle

Builder.load_string("""
<ButtonsApp>:
    ScrollView:
        id: sv
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: 205, 200
        size: 200, 600 
        on_scroll_stop: app.scroll_on_stop()
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        scroll_wheel_distance: 20
        bar_width: 8
        bar_inactive_color: .55, .55, .55, 1 
        bar_color: .663, .663, .663, 1 
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, .5, 1, 1
                group: 'b'
            Rectangle:
                size: 0, 0
                group: 'b'
        GridLayout:
            id: container
            cols: 1
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint: None, None
            do_scroll_x: False


""")

class ButtonsApp(App, FloatLayout):

    def build(self):
        global rolling_row_cnt
        global my_number_list
        global start_row 
        global end_row
        rolling_row_cnt = 0 #we will use this variable to keep track of the total number of rows in the scrollview as we add rows to it..
        my_number_list = []
        #create a list of numbers from 1 to 600 - this represents the max number of rows that can be displayed
        for i in range(0, 600):
            my_number_list.append(i)
        #we will start the scrollview only showing 100 rows to start.. 
        #as the user scrolls down the view we will add more rows (100 at a time) and adjust the scrollview upwards      
        start_row = 0
        end_row = 100
        self.modify_scrollview()
        return self

    def modify_scrollview(self):
        global rolling_row_cnt
        global my_number_list
        global start_row 
        global end_row
        for i in my_number_list[start_row:end_row]: #add 100 rows to the scrollview...
            L1 = Button(text="row = " + str(rolling_row_cnt), font_size=12, halign='left', valign='middle', size_hint=[None, None], height=37, width=60, background_color=[0, 0, 0, 1], color=[.92, .92, .92, 1])
            L1.bind(size=L1.setter('text_size'))  
            self.ids.container.add_widget(L1)
            rolling_row_cnt = rolling_row_cnt + 1
        if rolling_row_cnt > 99:
            print ("WRONG SCROLL_Y = " + str(self.ids.sv.scroll_y)) #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS - after you add rows to the existing scrollview through scroll_on_stop below,
        #the scroll_y value that gets calculated here is 0.0 which is WRONG. How do I get this value to update properly when new rows are added to the scrollview? If I add new rows and move the bar up using code,
        #it should give me the scroll_y at the current bar's position, not 0.0.. 

    def scroll_on_stop(self):
        global start_row 
        global end_row
        if self.ids.sv.scroll_y < .05: #if the user scrolls the view close to the bottom, we will add another 100 rows to the existing scrollview 
            start_row = start_row + 100
            end_row = end_row + 100
            self.modify_scrollview() #trigger the addition of 100 more rows to the existing scrollview
            self.root.ids.sv.scroll_to(self.root.ids.container.children[100]) #adjust the scrollview UPWARD to keep the last most row from last time in view for the user..
        print ("SCROLL_Y = " + str(self.ids.sv.scroll_y)) #this scroll_y is correct when you manually move the mouse wheel 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonsApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is two-fold.
First - I suspect that the `on_scroll_stop` event is not acting like you expect (it is not what I expected). Each mouse wheel scroll causes several `on_scroll_stop` events, not just one at the end of the scroll. This causes your `scroll_on_stop()` method to get called several times for every mouse wheel scroll.

Second - The `scroll_to()` method will delay itself (using `Clock.schedule.once()`) if there are other operations pending (like when rows are added to its child).

So, when `scroll_on_stop()` gets called multiple times, the `scroll_to()` gets delayed (`scroll_y` is not updated), resulting in an old value of `scroll_y` being reported.

I think you can work around this problem by not using `scroll_to()`, but just setting `scroll_y` instead. I suggest replacing your line:

```
self.root.ids.sv.scroll_to(self.root.ids.container.children[100])
```

with something like:

```
self.root.ids.sv.scroll_y = 100.0/end_row
```

This prevents the `scroll_on_stop()` from adding rows several times on one scroll, and should scroll to the desired row.

Comment: It would be nice to still utilize the "scroll_to" method and determine the appropriate scroll_y value. I also noticed that the "convert_scroll_to_distance" method also appears to not be working as well in this situation. I guess these issues are a source code problem. John's answer is a good workaround solution and still works in providing the scroll_y value in this situation. Thanks so much for your help!